# text in button not fully visible android

Tags: android, button, text

I am using a `Button` with a custom background. The text in the button is not fully visible. I tried the `weight` attribute, but it's still not working.

I am trying to add "Find Diamond" text to the second `button`.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_option_buttons"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:weightSum="5" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_news"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/shape1"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/news_tab"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="News"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="12dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_diamond_search"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"           
            android:background="@drawable/newsletter_selector"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/diamond_search_icon"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="Find Diamond"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="12dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_images"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/menu_photo_selector"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/photos_tab"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="Photos"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="12dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_videos"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/menu_video_selector"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/videos_tab"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="Videos"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="12dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_more"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/menu_dir_selector"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/directory_tab"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="Directory"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="12dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

I Increased the height of every button to 70dp, but layout got disturbed
[height Increased screen shot](https://www.flickr.com/photos/109729836@N08/15867979814/)

I set height to `wrap_content` of every button, but layout got disturbed
[wrap_content screen shot](https://www.flickr.com/photos/109729836@N08/16303086630/)

Comment: increase the height of your button or change it to wrap content

Comment: has your problem solved?

Comment: try setting the child buttons android:layout_height to fill_parent

Comment: the text "Find" and "Diamond" is display one below another

Comment: In each button change height width like this--                      **android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"**

Comment: in each button used android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"

Comment: @ Prashant Maheshwari Andro  --> ayout_height="wrap_content disturbs layout ..